# What does "bonding" mean with respect to wiring in an outbuilding?

Tags: electrical

In this statement, "You'll have to install an adequate grounding electrode system at the outbuilding, and bond the grounding conductor to it, "What is meant by bonding?"

Answer (score 1):

Bonding in the context you have provided means to connect or otherwise attach one item to another. Your grounding electrode system can be and frequently is an eight-foot copper clad rod embedded in the ground. Depending on the composition of your earth, it may be necessary to increase the length and depth. Consult your local codes regarding earth ground requirements.

The other part of the bonding is the segment of copper wire attached to the aforementioned ground rod. That is frequently a simple clamp available at big-box hardware stores and is called a grounding clamp. Imagine that. The ground wire also should meet local codes regarding wire gauge, often number six gauge (or at least in my area it is) and is fastened to the ground rod at one end and secured to the enclosure/panel at the other. The ground at the panel shares the connection with the ground lug for the breakers as well.

Comment: There also needs to be a grounding wire between the two buildings...

Comment: One would also hope that there is a solidly bonded and earthed ground at the primary building, or else there is a potential for imbalance.

Comment: The earth is a lousy conductor -- so even with ground electrodes at both buildings, it's still possible to get imbalances.

Answer (score 1):

"Bonding" means "Connecting, but in a very particular way".

Specifically, the connection from the ground rod to your electrical system should be made in the sub-panel, and to the ground bus only, since it's a sub-panel.  (in a main panel there would also be a bond between ground and neutral, but not here.)